# type casting long double to long long

Tags: c, types

I am doing type casting in C as follow

```
long double dec = 12.32;
long double n = dec - (long long)dec;
```

when i print 6 digits of n after the point "." assuming n is 0.32, it gives me 3, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9;
but when i do this cast

```
double n = dec - (int)dec;
```

the printing is correct (3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0) and i can't figure out why

The printing code is just :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   n *= 10;
   printf("%d digit = %d or %lld\n", i, (int) or (long long)n);
   n -= (int) or (long long)n;
}
```

Comment: Please make two [mcve]s. Also, by "all digits" you might demonstrate a lack of understanding of the representations of floating point values. How many digits do you think 0.1 has? Could you describe how you imagine the representation of 12.32?

Comment: what is `n`? printng code does ot have anything in common wit the first examples. Post complete code! But not your pseudocode

Comment: @Yunnosch Hi! Yes i was wrong there by saying all digits and 0.1 has more digits than 1 depending on the single or double precision storage if i am not wrong.n is just a variable that i use to store the decimal part of my floating point number.

Comment: Is this [What is the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you trying to do?  Apart from the casts, the code has no `long long` type. Did you mean `long long wholenum = dec;`? Or to the same type, `trunc()`, `round()` or `floor()`.

Comment: ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: "Could you describe how you imagine the representation of 12.32?" : if i am not wrong 12.32 is stored like this 1100.0111001100...; with a scientific notation 1.1000111001110... * 2^3

Comment: @WeatherVane I am tying to convert that in a string.

Comment: Then use `sprintf`. We don't *imagin*e the floating point representation. `double` is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) but `long double` is harder to find.

Comment: Just trying to reproduce the %Lf since i can't use sprintf cause i learn nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12.32 is not representable in the formats your C implementation uses for `long double` or `double`.

The closest representable value to 12.32 in `long double` may be 12.319999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875. This would partly explain why your program shows 3, 1, 9, 9, 9, and 9—those are the actual decimal digits of the number.

Similarly, the closest representable value to 12.32 in `double` may be 12.32000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125, and that would explain why your program shows 3, 2, 0, 0, 0 and 0.

However, in the code you show, `long double dec = 12.32;`, `12.32` is a `double` constant. It should have the `double` value even though you assign it to a `long double`. So that does not explain why your program shows 3, 1, 9, 9, 9, and 9. You would need the `l` suffix to make it a `long double` constant, as in `long double dec = 12.32l;`. Perhaps the code you show in the question is not exactly the code you used to produce 3, 1, 9, 9, 9, and 9.

Additionally, the code `n *= 10;` cannot be relied on to extract digits. This is because, in general, the mathematical result of multiplying a `double` or `long double` value by 10 is not representable in the `double` or `long double` format—since 10 requires three significant bits to represent (101<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>1</sup>), the exact product may require more significant bits than are in a `double`. In consequence, the exact mathematical result is rounded to fit in the floating-point format. In other words, `n *= 10;` changes the value; it does not just multiply it by 10. So it will not always produce the digits of the original number.

Comment: Ty for your answer, it makes things better but i didn't really understand why 10 would need a 3rd significant bit for 101 in base 2

Comment: @NumLock: Decimal 10 is binary 1010. The leading bit is the 1 of 1000. The trailing significant bit is the 1 of 10. So that is three significant bits, 101. (The trailing zero is just for scale.)

Answer (score -3):

It works OK. But your code have many issues:

`for (int i = 0; i++; i < 6)` does not do what  you think :) (see in my answer)

`printf` `long long` requires `%lld` and if you use `%d` it is undefined behavior

```
void foo(long double dec)
{
    long double n = dec - (long long)dec;
    
    for (int i = 0; i< 6; i++)
    {
        n *= 10;
        printf("%d digit = %lld\n", i, (long long)n);
        n -= (long long)n;
    }

    printf("%lld\n", (long long)(n * 100)); 
}

int main()
{
    foo(12.32);

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/DGvPQJ

## EDIT

It looks like your compiler unly uses floats not double or long double

Comment: Another silent DV-ter? Revenge? Moon phase? Hangover? Any other reason?

Comment: Hi! Yeah my bad on %lld but it still doesn't work even with the %lld

Comment: it does on 3 compilers I have.

Comment: Gonna update my own (gcc version 8.1.0 (Debian 8.1.0-12) ) then :( I was thinking about a compiler problem

Comment: It is not my down vote, but where is the answer in this answer? It does not discuss floating-point issues at all, except to say that “It looks like your compiler unly uses floats not double or long double,” which is rubbish.

Comment: @EricPostpischil only float does not keep this value and gives the observable by the OP result.

Comment: @P__J__: No, setting `dec` to the `long double` value (where `long double` uses Intel’s 80-bit format) nearest to 12.32 produces the result OP reported.

Comment: no modern compiler use lagacy x87 modes only SSL ones